# fastest way to set every pixel

Tags: c++, opengl, pixel, blit

I have programmed a little raytracer in c++,
and want to show the raytraced image in a window.

I tried using a `pixel buffer object` in `opengl`,
then map the buffer into memory and manipulate the pixels one by one,
but at fullscreen resolution 1920x1080, I only get `4 fps`
**without raytracing** and **without changing the pixels colors**
just the mapping and unmapping!

so i'm basically looking for the fastest way to display a raytraced image in a window.

i'm currently doing this way:

```
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, pbo);
glBufferDataARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, width * height * 4, 0, GL_STREAM_DRAW_ARB);
if (pixels = (uint*)glMapBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, GL_WRITE_ONLY_ARB))
{
    //modify pixels
    glUnmapBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB);
}
else
    return;


//copy from pbo to texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pbo_texture);
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, pbo);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

//draw image
glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pbo_texture);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f( 1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f( 1.0,  1.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-1.0,  1.0, 0.0);
glEnd();

glutSwapBuffers();

glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Comment: Don't you think the raytracer is the bottleneck here>?

Comment: as i said, i get 4fps without raytracing... only mapping buffer and unmapping

Comment: Sound weird. Put the code of how you do it.

Comment: PBOs are most useful if you map them, modify data, unmap them and then do something *UNRELATED* to OpenGL. The idea is that you do not have to stall the pipeline and synch the GPU and CPU; DMA data transfer can occur while your application uses the CPU to do something else. As-per your strange title for this question, `glClear (...)` is the fastest way to set every pixel :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the memory traversal if you use loops. You should traverse your buffer in the right order, otherwise you may have cache miss at each iteration. If you use nested loops sometimes you only have to switch the x/y iteration order.

Also, don't read data from graphic memory. It tends to be slow. Only write to PBO.

It looks like a syncro issue. I'm not sure you need to map pbo at every frame.  Check this link on [OpenGL Pixel Buffer Object (PBO)](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html). There's also a workaround for stalls which could improve things

Comment: That should be a comment. Based on his current question state it's impossible to see what's the problem .

Comment: got it, i changed the loop iteration order and now it works, thanks!